# Nuxt store inside cypress test

Tags: nuxt.js, store

I have a nuxt 2 application and I want to test a component using cypress (component testing).
I have a file called Comments.cy.js which imports my component and I want to know how to mount my component with the store.
An example below:

```js
import Comments from '../../components/Comments.vue';
    
describe('<Comments />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        cy.mount(Comments, {
            store,
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to add a plugin/cypress.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import CommonModule from '../store/main'

Vue.use(Vuex);

function getStore() {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            common: CommonModule
        },
    });
};

export default getStore;
```

but when I test it, it seems like to be adapted for Vue applications and not for Nuxt. How the plugin/cypress.js should look like ?